# Reference pivot table in sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a table called Permission Master, which has data like this:

[image]

I want to create one more table in which I will map the Acronym of above table as mentioned below

[image]

What I want to do is if any row is added in the PermissionMaster Table then that row acronym value should be added as a column in second table.

Object table

[image]

Comment: Do you have another table to store each user's permissions?

Comment: We also need to see the Users table, the Objects table, and the User-Objects-Permissions table. Also, if there are no permissions for a user at all, do you still need the pivot to show a row for the user?

Comment: HI Wewesthemenace. No In second table only I am storing the user permission vs object.

Comment: HI StuartLC, the second table is only User-Objects-Permissions table and users table has only some column about the user info thats it and object table has columns like ObjectID, ObjectType,TableName, Description.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic crosstab here:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93114/1/0)

First, create your sample datA:

```
CREATE TABLE PermissionMaster(
    Id      INT,
    Acronym VARCHAR(10),
    Description VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO PermissionMaster VALUES
(1, 'VIEW', 'View'),
(2, 'DOWNLOAD', 'Download'),
(3, 'DELETE', 'Delete'),
(4, 'EDIT', 'Edit'),
(5, 'MOVE', 'Move');

CREATE TABLE UserPermission(
    UserId  INT,
    ObjectId INT,
    ObjectType INT,
    PermissionId INT
)
INSERT INTO UserPermission VALUES
(9003, 5789, 2, 1), (9003, 5789, 2, 2),
(9067, 8768, 1, 1), (9067, 8768, 1, 3), (9067, 8768, 1, 5),
(9786, 4535, 3, 1), (9786, 4535, 3, 4);
```

Dynamic crosstab:

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    UserId
    , ObjectId
    , ObjectType' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , SUM(CASE WHEN PermissionId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Id) + ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Description) + CHAR(10)
FROM PermissionMaster
ORDER BY Id

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM UserPermission
GROUP BY UserId, ObjectId, ObjectType
ORDER BY UserId'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

**RESULT**

```
| UserId | ObjectId | ObjectType | View | Download | Delete | Edit | Move |
|--------|----------|------------|------|----------|--------|------|------|
|   9003 |     5789 |          2 |    1 |        1 |      0 |    0 |    0 |
|   9067 |     8768 |          1 |    1 |        0 |      1 |    0 |    1 |
|   9786 |     4535 |          3 |    1 |        0 |      0 |    1 |    0 |
```

Comment: Yes wewesthemenace, we thought about this approach to store the data. but in system there are many objects and users so according this approach UserPermission table will have too many rows which will cause performance issue, that's why we didn't consider this approach.

Comment: So, instead of adding rows per permission, you're adding a column?

Comment: and we don't want to show as a report this result. actually after saving in pivot form will insert the same data in elastic search indexes to make system faster.

Comment: Yes I am adding as a column because permissions will be limited, hardly 30 permissions

Comment: That's very impractical IMHO. You're better off saving one row for each `user`-`object`-`permission` combination. Adding a column whenever a new `permission` is added is not the way to go. Besides, if your tables are properly indexed, the query above will be fast.

Comment: You don't know that. Somewhere along the road you'll add another permission making it `31`. If you want to go that road, make sure your `permission`s are fixed.

Comment: Yes but in the application there are aprox 1000000 folders and in each folder minimum 5-15 assets are there. and some 300 users are there per tenant. so it will be very difficult to maintain the performance.

Comment: yes no problem wewesthemenace. 31st will come it will get added as a column and it will take default value false for all user.